# Can the Maps App be launched by NFC using a URL in the tag?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to find a way to launch the maps app, with lon/lat and preferrably the style (aerial), from a URL.  I've tried as suggested elsewhere to use bing map URL construction as shown here: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808440.aspx but it doesn't seem to work.  At least on my Lumia 822, it opens in IE10 instead of the app (of course, they switched to Nokia maps).  Is there a way to construct a url that will open in a WP8 in the maps app instead of the browser (I guess WP7 doesn't matter, since I'm talking NFC...)?

I also tried using a uri with explore-maps://......  But in another question Justin Angel said that Nokia's position is that this is not supported, and will potentially be broken in the future.  Otherwise it works - for now at least.  I'd like a way that's not going to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More information about storing geo coordinates on an NFC tag can be found via this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13759.how-to-store-geo-coordinates-on-an-nfc-tag.aspx

It also has some more information about writing the tags with your own application.

And another link which might help you that can be found on the previous link is this one: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Code/2012/03/22/cross-platform-nfc-geo-tags/ It is a blog post about Geo Tags from March 2012, with a more Nokia-focused perspective.

All these links and posts are made by Andreas Jakl, responsible for NDEF library for Proximity APIs.

Comment: Excellent information - thanks!  Now why didn't I see either of those in my searching... ???  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone accepts "maps:" protocol, so you can just go ahead and create an NFC tag with url like "maps:1234,5678" and the Windows Phone Maps application will open that for you!

Comment: To clarify, the maps URI only fully works with windows phone 7, for windows phone 8, it will open the bing map, but ignore the  cordinates....